# PyQT show FTP server's content using QTreeView

Tags: python-3.x, ftp, pyqt

I'm writing an FTP client GUI. I want it to look something like this, so I could move around the folder, and also right-click on the file or folder and download it to local machine:

[image]

I guess I need to do something like this, but I don't know, how to add files I get from the server to the tree. So, any suggestions where  to look for the info?

```
def _print_list(self):
    if self.thread and self.thread.is_alive():
        return
    files = self._ftp.nlst().split('\r\n') 
      # all the folders and files in current directory

    path = self._ftp.extract_path_from_pwd_reply()
      # current directory

    widget = QWidget(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    model = QFileSystemModel()

    #and here I want to do something like:
    for file in files:
        model.add(file)
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            # change directory and run again?

    tree = QTreeView()
    tree.setModel(model)

    tree.setAnimated(False)
    tree.setIndentation(20)
    tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

    windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    windowLayout.addWidget(tree)
    widget.setLayout(windowLayout)
```

Comment: Your question is much too broad. You need to break in down into a set of smaller problems and solve each one in turn. I assume you are using [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html). If so, your first task will be to write a basic [custom model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference) that wraps `ftplib` and is able to display directories and files hierarchically. The [simple tree model example](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/itemviews/simpletreemodel) should help get you started.